# How to evaluate a string as a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to make a website that lets users input some react code, then it renders it on the other side of the page, so they can see what it looks like.

My problem is, I have the user's source code as a string (which may return a function or class component), but I don't know how to convert that to an actual react component that can be rendered.

First I tried using the `new Function()` constructor, which lets you create a function from a string, which looks like this:

```
import {render} from "react-dom"

const userInputtedCode = `
return function App() {
    return <div>Hello world</div>
}
`

const func = new Function("React", userInputtedCode);
const App = func(React)
render(<App/>, document.getElementById('WorkFlow'));
```

But this doesn't work, as I get the error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

I have also tried libraries such as `react-jsx-parser`, but this doesn't fit what I need, as I want to make an entire react component which may contain state, props, nested components, etc, not just parse some JSX.

Any ideas of how I can convert strings of source code that return a function/class into actual react components? Thanks!

Comment: JSX is transpiled with babel before the code is even send to the browser

Comment: Is that for learning purposes? Any advantage over codesandbox / stackblitz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import * as babel from "babel-standalone";

const userInputtedCode = `
function App() {
    return <div>Hello world</div>
}
`;
const babelCode = babel.transform(userInputtedCode, {
  presets: ["react", "es2017"]
}).code;

const code = babelCode.replace('"use strict";', "").trim();
const func = new Function("React", `return ${code}`);
const App = func(React);
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

PS: Make sure to run `npm i babel-standalone` before running the app.

Comment: This works for the example, and works with other examples such as adding `const data = 0` inside the App function and then `return <div>Data is {data}</div>`, but if instead of `const data = 0` you put `const [data, setData] = React.useState(0)` it does not work, it gives the error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'` - why is this, and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: `const babelCode = babel.transform(userInputtedCode, {
  presets: ["react", "es2017"]
}).code;
` Change the ES version to `es2017` and it should work! @Yankue