# How do I pass an entire image element as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-props, react-image

I am getting a JSON response that has an image property for each key. This image property is the entire image element tag with properties. I am trying to pass that down into a child component, but upon attempting to render, it just shows up as plain html text on the page. Is there a way to render it as an actual image tag?
[I have attached a screenshot of the JSON response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYYWs.png)

```
           ` <div className="aspect-[3/2] md:aspect-square overflow-hidden">
        {props.image}
    </div>
    <span className="block py-5">{props.name}</span>`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620013/how-to-evaluate-a-string-as-a-react-component Please have a look at this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but you'll have to wrap it in a span or div or something:

```js
// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
    render() {
    
        const {source} = this.props;
        console.log("rendered");
        return (
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: source }} />
        );
    }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <Thingy source={`<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490730141103-6cac27aaab94?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" />`} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```