# Function is not getting called in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, function

I am having below code.

```
if (response.ok) {
  response.json().then((data: any) => {
    //use data
    console.log(data.value);
    let strFilesDisplayTable = "";
    strFilesDisplayTable =
      "<table border='1'> <tr> <th> Name </th> <th > Uploaded Date </th> <th > Role </th>  <th > Remove </th></tr>";
    for (var c = 0; c < data.value.length; c++) {
      var dateVal = new Date(data.value[c].TimeCreated);
      var docIdVal = data.value[c].ListItemAllFields["Role"];
      let dateTimeCreatedMod =
        dateVal.getDate().toString() +
        "/" +
        (dateVal.getMonth() + 1).toString() +
        "/" +
        dateVal.getFullYear().toString();

      strFilesDisplayTable =
        strFilesDisplayTable +
        "<tr> <td > " +
        data.value[c].Title +
        " </td> <td>" +
        data.value[c].Title +
        " </td> <td style='padding:5px;'> " +
        dateTimeCreatedMod +
        " </td> <td style='padding:5px;'> " +
        data.value[c].ListItemAllFields["Role"] +
        "  </td> <td> <button class='btnDelDoc'  onClick={this.tempFunDel(" +
        data.value[c].ListItemAllFields["ID"] +
        ")}> Delete </button> </td> </tr> ";
    }
    strFilesDisplayTable = strFilesDisplayTable + "</table>";
    document.getElementById("showFilesDiv").innerHTML = strFilesDisplayTable;
  });
}
```

and my function is

`public tempFunDel(idVa){ alert("Id is !" +idVa); }`

It renders one table for me. When I click on delete button nothing happens `function "tempFunDel"` is not getting called. Please suggest a workaround to call the function in the HTML string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This is React but you're building up HTML in strings and setting it manually?!

Comment: Tangential, but a 400+ char line is... scroll-y.

Comment: You will need to evaluate the string

Comment: you're asking the community to donate their time to help you. can you at least format your code properly?

Comment: @DaveNewton it's more scroll-x :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620013/how-to-evaluate-a-string-as-a-react-component/74620109#74620109 This might help you to evaluate the string to be a valid HTML

Comment: it is an antipattern in react to use `document.getElement*`, `document.query*`, and `element.innerHTML = ...`

Answer (score 1):

It is an anti-pattern in React to assemble HTML using strings and updating the DOM with the `innerHTML` property. Instead components accept properties and construct HTML elements directly using inline JSX . <kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below to see a minimal, reproducible example in your own browser.

```js
function Table({ cols = [], rows = [] }) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
         {cols.map((c, key) =>
           <td key={key}>{c}</td>
         )}
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((r, key) =>
          <tr key={key}>
            {cols.map((c, key) =>
              <td key={key}>{r[c]}</td>
            )}
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

const data = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 30 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 40 },
  { name: "Charlie", age: 50 },
]

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <Table cols={["name", "age"]} rows={data} />
)
```

```css
thead { font-weight: bold; }
tr ~ tr td { border-top: 1px solid silver; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If the data for the Table is arriving asynchronously, a parent component can handle the request, the supplying the data to the table as props after it has loaded successfully.

```js
function App({ url }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(
    () => {
      let mounted = true
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.ok) return res.json()
          else throw Error("could not load data")
        })
        .then(data => mounted && setData(data))
        .catch(console.error)
      return () => { mounted = false }
    },
    [url]
  )
  return data.length == 0
    ? <Loading />
    : <Table cols={["name", "age"]} rows={data} />
}
```

Of course you can imagine a big headache if you have to write this for every component that needs to make a JSON request. Writing good programs means extracting behaviors so they can be easily reused -

```js
function useJSON(url, initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)
  useEffect(
    () => {
      let mounted = true
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.ok) return res.json()
          else throw Error("could not load data")
        })
        .then(data => mounted && setData(data))
        .catch(console.error)
      return () => { mounted = false }
    },
    [url]
  )
}
```

Now writing `App` is a breeze -

```js
import { useJSON } from "./hooks.jsx"

function App({ url }) {
  const data = useJSON(url, [])
  return data.length == 0
    ? <Loading />
    : <Table cols={["name", "age"]} rows={data} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the following in your structure:

```
onClick={this.tempFunDel("+data.value[c].ListItemAllFields['ID']+")}
```

To call a function with parameters, according to the official documentation, you have to do the following:

```
onClick={() => this.tempFunDel("+data.value[c].ListItemAllFields['ID']+")}
```

Link to the ReactJS documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers